# Bluetooth Low energy chip range

Tags: bluetooth

I'm currently trying to configure a device that I can connect via Bluetooth to my cell phone. I want the device Bluetooth range about  15 feet. How do I control a Bluetooth range?

Comment: What device? What phone? Do you have line of sight?

Comment: Most bluetooth low energy components let you set the transmit power level, but realize range is going to be approximate.  Success over 15 feet seems readily achievable though.

Comment: need more details about the device that you are trying to configure.

Comment: With only a handful of embedded BLE chips on the market, we may actually *not* need more information - the capabilities of those that are out there are fairly comparable, many of them likely falling right out of the spec.

Comment: I'm working on a new device that needs to be able work with any phone. If the transmit power level adjustable then that is exactly what I need. I need a approximate range so that is also perfect.

Comment: I'm doing this for a school project.

Comment: Is there a way I can link a light and a alarm to the device which blinks and sounds as soon as it loses the Bluetooth connectivity with the phone?

Answer (score 1):

**Classic Bluetooth** has 3 different classes which specify range.

```
Class     Maximum Power      Operating Range
Class 1   100mW (20dBm)   100 meters (330 Feet)
Class 2    2.5mW (4dBm)    10 meters (33 Feet)
Class 3      1mW (0dBm)     1 meter (3.3 Feet)
```

In practice, I have found most Class 2 Bluetooth devices  have a range of about 10 feet reliably.

Range is also affected by the usually things that effect a radio signal: Interference, antenna, walls, metal surfaces etc.

In your case you are using **BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy)** which does not specify range like Classic Bluetooth. So range will depend on the reasons given above and also the module you are working with, and whether it has the capability to adjust power level.

Comment: He asked about BLE, not classic Bluetooth for which your numbers don't apply.